# Ant failed to create task or type apt

Tags: java, ant, classpath, relative-path, build.xml

**Command**

```
ant
```

I am trying to run ant task on my local machine but I keep getting the same error message as shown below when I ran ant command (build.xml is in the same directory /home/lushen/batman)

**Error Message:**

```
Buildfile: /home/lushen/batman/build.xml

init:
     [echo] Building batman-0.1

prepare:

prepare-java:

compile-java:

BUILD FAILED
/home/lushen/batman/build.xml:102: Problem: failed to create task or type apt
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.


Total time: 0 seconds
```

The build.xml is placed under the directory /home/lushen/batman and build.xml script is shown as below.

**build.xml file**

```
  <project name="batman" default="all" basedir=".">
  <property environment="env" />

  <target name="all" depends="package-java" />

  <!-- Checks environment and setup variables -->
  <target name="init" description="Checks environment and setup variables">
    <tstamp />
    <property name="version" value="0.1" />

    <property name="build.compiler" value="modern" />

    <property name="bin.dir" value="./bin" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="./lib" />
    <property name="src.main.dir" value="./src" />
    <property name="manifest.dir" value="./manifest" />
    <property name="resources.dir" value="./resources" />

    <property name="classpath" value="${lib.dir}/biojava.jar:${lib.dir}/bytecode.jar:${lib.dir}/bjv2-core-0.1.jar:${lib.dir}/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:${lib.dir}/colt.jar" />

    <!-- Main build directory -->
    <property name="build.dir" value="./ant-build" />
    <property name="build.classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes" />

    <!-- Javac properties -->
    <property name="javac.depend" value="false" />
    <property name="javac.debug" value="true" />
    <property name="javac.deprecation" value="false" />
    <property name="javac.source" value="1.5" />

    <!-- Javadoc properties -->
    <property name="build.dest.docs" value="${build.dir}/docs" />
    <property name="build.dest.doccheck" value="${build.dir}/docs/check" />
    <property name="packages" value="net.*" />

    <!-- Subdirectories for main source and classes -->
    <property name="name.main" value="batman" />
    <property name="Name.main" value="Batman" />
    <property name="build.dest.main" value="${build.classes.dir}/${name.main}" />
    <property name="build.docs.main" value="${build.dest.docs}/${name.main}" />
    <property name="jar.main" value="${lib.dir}/${name.main}.jar" />
    <property name="manifest.file.main" value="${manifest.dir}/${name.main}.txt" />

    <!-- Echo information -->
    <echo message="Building ${name.main}-${version}" />
  </target>


  <!--
    Prepare each part of the project.
    Each preparation creates working directories and copies files over.
  -->

  <!-- Prepares the basic stuff -->
  <target name="prepare" depends="init" description="creates basic directories">
    <!-- Creates directories -->
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Prepares the source code -->
  <target name="prepare-java" depends="prepare" description="Prepares java source files">
    <!-- Creates directories -->
    <mkdir dir="${build.dest.main}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build.docs.main}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Prepares the javadocs -->
  <target name="prepare-javadocs" depends="prepare" description="Prepares the javadocs">
    <!-- Creates directories -->
    <mkdir dir="${build.dest.docs}" />
  </target>


  <!-- Compiles the source directory -->
  <target name="compile-java" depends="prepare-java" description="Compiles the java source code">
    <apt
      destdir="${build.dest.main}"
      depend="${javac.depend}"
      deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"
      debug="${javac.debug}"
      srcdir="${src.main.dir}">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${classpath}" />
    <pathelement path="${build.dest.build}" />
      </classpath>

      <filename name="batman/**/*.java" />
    </apt>
  </target>
```

In addition, I have sourced the ant and edit the ant.sh file under the directory /etc/profile.d as shown below.

**ant.sh file**

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant
export PATH=${ANT_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

I have never used Java so my questions may be silly. I have read through similar questions on the forum but none of them could solve my problem. I am using Ubuntu, Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.5 compiled on July 10 2018, and  openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17.Changing Java and ant to older version did not help to solve the problem. BioJava has been installed.

I've also tried to replace all the 'apt' into 'javac' in build.xml, but I am getting the following error message this time:

**New error message if replace 'apt' with 'javac' in build.xml**

```
Buildfile: /home/lushen/batman/build.xml

init:
     [echo] Building batman-0.1

prepare:

prepare-java:

compile-java:
    [javac] Compiling 55 source files to /home/lushen/batman/ant-build/classes/batman
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/AddExpt.java:6: error: package org.biojava.utils does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.utils.JDBCPooledDataSource;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/AddExpt.java:7: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.App;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/AddExpt.java:8: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.Option;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/AddExpt.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @App(overview="Add experiment metadata to a Batman DB", generateStub=true)
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class App
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:16: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFDocumentHandler;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:17: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFParser;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:18: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFRecord;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:19: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.DNATools;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:20: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.Sequence;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:21: error: package org.biojava.bio.symbol does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.symbol.Location;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:22: error: package org.biojava.bio.symbol does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.symbol.LocationTools;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:23: error: package org.biojava.bio.symbol does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.symbol.RangeLocation;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:24: error: package org.biojava.bio.symbol does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.symbol.SimpleSymbolList;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:25: error: package org.biojava.bio.symbol does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.symbol.Symbol;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:26: error: package org.biojava.bio.symbol does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.symbol.SymbolList;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:27: error: package org.biojava.utils does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.utils.JDBCPooledDataSource;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:28: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.App;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:29: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.Option;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @App(overview="Perform per-array calibration of the Batman model", generateStub=true)
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class App
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private Map<String,Location> mask = null;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Location
    [javac]   location: class Calibrate
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:170: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private double tm(SymbolList sl)
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class SymbolList
    [javac]   location: class Calibrate
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:186: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private final Symbol C = DNATools.c();
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Symbol
    [javac]   location: class Calibrate
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Calibrate.java:187: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private final Symbol G = DNATools.g();
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Symbol
    [javac]   location: class Calibrate
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DmrT.java:12: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFDocumentHandler;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DmrT.java:13: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFParser;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DmrT.java:14: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFRecord;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DmrT.java:15: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFWriter;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DmrT.java:16: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.SimpleGFFRecord;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DmrT.java:17: error: package org.bjv2.util does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.SmallMap;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DmrT.java:18: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.App;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DmrT.java:19: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.Option;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DmrT.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @App(overview="...", generateStub=true)
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class App
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DmrT.java:146: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private Map<String,GFFRecord> loadGFF(String fileName)
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class GFFRecord
    [javac]   location: class DmrT
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DumpMedipGFF.java:9: error: package org.biojava.utils does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.utils.JDBCPooledDataSource;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DumpMedipGFF.java:10: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.App;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DumpMedipGFF.java:11: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.Option;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DumpMedipGFF.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @App(overview="Re-export MeDIP data from a Batman DB", generateStub=true)
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class App
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DumpMedipGFF2.java:9: error: package org.biojava.utils does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.utils.JDBCPooledDataSource;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DumpMedipGFF2.java:10: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.App;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DumpMedipGFF2.java:11: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.Option;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/DumpMedipGFF2.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @App(overview="Re-export MeDIP data from a Batman DB", generateStub=true)
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class App
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/EstimateCouplingProfile.java:5: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.App;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/EstimateCouplingProfile.java:6: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.Option;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/EstimateCouplingProfile.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @App(overview="Probe-coupling simulation", generateStub=true)
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class App
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/FitBeta.java:11: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.App;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/FitBeta.java:16: error: package cern.jet.stat does not exist
    [javac] import cern.jet.stat.Gamma;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/FitBeta.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @App(overview="MCMC fit of a Beta distribution to some data", generateStub=true)
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class App
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadCouplingProfile.java:8: error: package org.biojava.utils does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.utils.JDBCPooledDataSource;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadCouplingProfile.java:9: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.App;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadCouplingProfile.java:10: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.Option;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadCouplingProfile.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @App(overview="Load a coupling profile into a Batman DB", generateStub=true)
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class App
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:10: error: package org.biojava.bio does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.Annotation;
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:11: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.DNATools;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:12: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.Sequence;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:13: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.SequenceIterator;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:14: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq.db does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.db.HashSequenceDB;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:15: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq.db does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.db.SequenceDB;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:16: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq.impl does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.impl.SimpleSequence;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:17: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq.io does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.io.SeqIOTools;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:18: error: package org.biojava.bio.symbol does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.symbol.Symbol;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:19: error: package org.biojava.utils does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.utils.JDBCPooledDataSource;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:20: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.App;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:21: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.Option;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @App(overview="Load genomic sequence into a Batman DB", generateStub=true)
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class App
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadGenomeTiles.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private SequenceDB seqdb;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class SequenceDB
    [javac]   location: class LoadGenomeTiles
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadProbes.java:10: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFDocumentHandler;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadProbes.java:11: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFParser;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadProbes.java:12: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFRecord;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadProbes.java:13: error: package org.biojava.utils does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.utils.JDBCPooledDataSource;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadProbes.java:14: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.App;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadProbes.java:15: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.Option;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadProbes.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @App(overview="Load probe and ROI data into a Batman database", generateStub=true)
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class App
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadProbes.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private String gaga(GFFRecord r, String key)
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class GFFRecord
    [javac]   location: class LoadProbes
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadProbes.java:110: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private String gaga2(GFFRecord r, String key1, String key2)
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class GFFRecord
    [javac]   location: class LoadProbes
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadRatsGFF.java:8: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFDocumentHandler;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadRatsGFF.java:9: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFParser;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadRatsGFF.java:10: error: package org.biojava.bio.program.gff does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.program.gff.GFFRecord;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadRatsGFF.java:11: error: package org.biojava.utils does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.utils.JDBCPooledDataSource;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadRatsGFF.java:12: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.App;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadRatsGFF.java:13: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.Option;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadRatsGFF.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @App(overview="Load almost-Nimblegen-style GFF log-ratio data into Batman DB", generateStub=true)
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class App
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/LoadRatsGFF.java:128: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private String gaga(GFFRecord r, String key)
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class GFFRecord
    [javac]   location: class LoadRatsGFF
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:15: error: package org.biojava.bio does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.Annotation;
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:16: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.DNATools;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:17: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.Sequence;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:18: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.SequenceIterator;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:19: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq.db does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.db.HashSequenceDB;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:20: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq.db does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.db.SequenceDB;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:21: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq.impl does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.impl.SimpleSequence;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:22: error: package org.biojava.bio.seq.io does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.bio.seq.io.SeqIOTools;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:23: error: package org.biojava.utils does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.utils.JDBCPooledDataSource;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:24: error: package org.biojava.utils.xml does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.utils.xml.PrettyXMLWriter;
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:25: error: package org.biojava.utils.xml does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.utils.xml.XMLWriter;
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:26: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.App;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:27: error: package org.bjv2.util.cli does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.cli.Option;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:38: error: package cern.colt.list does not exist
    [javac] import cern.colt.list.DoubleArrayList;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @App(overview="Sample from Batman model for a group of probes", generateStub=true)
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class App
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/SampleMethStates.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private SequenceDB seqdb;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class SequenceDB
    [javac]   location: class SampleMethStates
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Summarize.java:19: error: package org.biojava.utils does not exist
    [javac] import org.biojava.utils.JDBCPooledDataSource;
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /home/lushen/batman/src/batman/Summarize.java:20: error: package org.bjv2.util does not exist
    [javac] import org.bjv2.util.SmallSet;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 100 errors
    BUILD FAILED
/home/lushen/batman/build.xml:103: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds
```

It seems that I did not install a bunch of relevant packages. But I have no idea how to install them..

Please help me to solve the "failed to create task or type apt" problem when I ran ant. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Checking your env I saw that you are using

> openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17.

And the apt function of ant only works for :

> This task runs on Java 1.5 to Java 1.7.
>
> Apt is deprecated in Java 1.6, which can run annotation processors as
>   part of javac, and removed from the distribution in Java 1.8. The task
>   will fire an exception when attempting to run under Java 1.8.

From [Ant Documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual-1.9.x/Tasks/apt.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! I am changing my Java version now!

Comment: @LuanChen Why change your Java version just so you can use a deprecated task? It was deprecated for a reason. Just use the `javac` task instead.

Comment: Right, changing Java version to 1.7 did not help but making ant not working. I will try javac today. Thank you for reminding me this!

Comment: @CAustin But simply replacing all the apt into javac in build.xml produced error message like "compile failed". What should I do from now?